# Where to find neighborhood boundaries for Israel?

Tags: polygon, administrative-boundaries, data, israel

Is there a place that has neighborhood boundary data for Israeli cities as polygons?

I have searched the web without results.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a freely available, nation-wide polygon layer.
You can try contacting MAPI regarding their [Cadastral](http://mapi.gov.il/ProductCatalog/Pages/bankal.aspx) data which might have neighborhoods, or the CBS/MoI statistical region layer. (If you don't know what these are, search for them on [govmap](http://govmap.gov.il/))
Other than that, your only option is a point layer with neighborhood names as found in Open Street Map.

**Update:**
I asked around, the [Ministry of Construction and Housing](http://www.moch.gov.il/english/Pages/HomePage.aspx) might have such a layer for some cities. Try contacting them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check this out ? http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata if this is what you were looking for ?